# Interbase XE7 Precedence using Brackets

Tags: sql, interbase, operator-precedence

To demonstrate the issue I am having, I am using a single table which has a DATE and a TIME field as part of the record.
For the example I wish to filter from 07:00 on one day to 06:59 the next day, so my query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM V_W1W2_LOGS WHERE (V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_DATE >= '2015-05-20' AND V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_TIME >= '07:00:00') AND (V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_DATE<='2015-05-22' AND V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_TIME < '07:00:00')
```

(*Above will not return any rows. Seems to behave as if there was no change of precedence from the brackets*)

As a test I did the following.
If I remove the time constraint from the 2nd part of the 'AND' the rows will be returned, starting at the 07:00 but for the full period of the following day.

```
(...) WHERE (V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_DATE >= '2015-05-20' AND V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_TIME >= '07:00:00') AND (V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_DATE<='2015-05-22')
```

(*Returns Rows from 07:00 as expected*)

Is there something obviously wrong with the query?
I tried more brackets, different date formats etc but it made no difference.
It seems to behave as if the brackets were not there.

I have not seen any issues to do with this in my trawl. If there was a timestamp in the record it would probably more straightforward but this is not the case.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

James F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer to fanaghirocco.

You should use `timestamp` instead `date` and `time` separately.
Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
 WHERE
cast (fdate ||' '||ftime as timestamp) >= '2015-05-01 07:00:00'
 and
cast (fdate ||' '||ftime as timestamp) < '2015-05-02 07:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks to you both for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is using both:

`V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_TIME >= '07:00:00'`

... `AND` ...

`V_W1W2_LOGS.W1_TIME < '07:00:00'`

... which is a *nonsense*.

Maybe did you mean `OR` in between the two?

Comment: The Time expression is used twice but is within parenthesis AND 'ed with a different date. I would have expected the 2 expressions within the brackets to be evaluated first?

Comment: `AND` conditions are always evaluate together. You must think about parenthesis only if you write `(... AND ...) OR (... AND ...)`

Comment: write `... AND ... AND ... AND ...` is the same as `(... AND ...) AND (... AND ...)`